# Why was Snarl not in The Transformers: The Movie?

Tags: transformers

[Snarl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snarl_(Transformers)) appeared only [very briefly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snarl_(Transformers)#Animated_series) in [The Transformers: The Movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transformers:_The_Movie):

[image: Screen capture from Wikipedia]

However, neither the Wikipedia article nor the [Transformers wiki](http://transformers.wikia.com/wiki/The_Transformers:_The_Movie#Trivia_and_controversies) provide a decent answer.

I'm looking for a real world answer, but if there is a decent in universe answer as well, then that is a bonus.

Comment: TFWiki says pretty much the same thing. Well, if the **very** knowledgeable folk over there don't know, I'm not sure another answer is available.

Comment: I mean, they had a lot of Transformers to focus on, and a load more to introduce.

Answer (score 29):

I decided to email the voice actor (Hal Rayle)  who played Snarl in the original Transformers series.

> **Question:** Was there any reason that Snarl had such a limited role in The Transformers Movie (1986) ?
>
> **Hal Rayle:** It was out of my control.  Based on other powers that be.
>
> **Question:**  Perhaps you could elaborate a little more. Was it simply that the character was forgotten (due to the large cast of the movie) or was there a decision by someone to minimize that character?
>
> **Hal Rayle:** It was out of my hands.  I suspect it had to do with toy sales and the powers that be.

Comment: Could you email "The powers that be"?

Comment: @DavRob60 If the "powers that be" even deign to answer, it'll probably be something like "synergy market cap paradigm revenue synergy synergy".

Comment: "Unmaskable data-stream interface quickly became an industry standard, paradigmed the markets."

Answer (score -2):

I always believed he was killed in the battle of autobot city, we just didn't see his death (just like we didn't see Wheeljack's).

It may just be my head canon, but it's better than "they forgot"

Comment: This is, as you say, without any particular foundation.

Comment: Also, the question was primarily asking for an _out-of-universe_ explanation as to why Snarl was given so little screen time in the movie.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's because Snarl is solar powered and therefore may not be of use in space missions.  This was the only excuse I could come up with that is nerd-worthy.

> His unique design makes Snarl particularly useful in sunny, arid environments. The large golden plates protruding from his spinal assembly are solar collectors. Although he can operate without sunlight, solar energy can increase his strength tenfold and his endurance to a virtually limitless degree. A swipe of his tail can shatter a 20-foot concrete cube. His heavily armored hide makes him resistant to most missile fire.
>
> Snarl's dependency on sunlight makes him extremely vulnerable to attack at night. Although he can use the same fuel the other Autobots use, he operates at only a fraction of his strength when he does. He is also very slow and his uncooperative behavior patterns sometimes hinder his effectivess in dangerous situations.
>
> <sub>- [Wikipedia's page on him](http://%20en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snarl_%28Transformers%29)</sub>

Comment: We prefer answers that have sources in this site. Do you have any source for this?

Comment: Wikipedia states that he was built so that he absorbs sunlight making him a thousand times more powerful.  His golden plates are solar panels.  It also states that he is extremely vulnerable to attack at night because of this.  Space being perpetual night would lead me to conclude that his usefulness on space missions would be lessened. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snarl_%28Transformers%29

Comment: Are you aware that solar power is more powerful in space, not less?

Comment: Solar power would be more powerful without the atmosphere to obstruct it while near a sun, yes. But, it would be less powerful the further you traveled from it. I think a better question would be "Were the creators of Transformers aware of this?".